# Link tag destroying page design

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a portfolio and I've come across this problem:
When I apply a link tag (*<a>*) it destroys the design I've made.
The font size is much smaller and the font isn't as smooth, here is an example:
  [image: Example of the problem]
What can i do to prevent this?
I've considered using js for handling the links entirely (I'm going to use some js for these any way).
**EDIT:**
Sorry, should have included the source:
**HTML:**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<nav>
    <div class="navwrap">
        <div class="logo inline"></div>
        <a href="#a"><div class="inline">About</div></a>
        <a href="#p"><div class="inline">Projects</div></a>
        <a href="#c"><div class="inline">Code</div></a>
        <a href="#l"><div class="inline">Learn</div></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #e3e3e3;
}

a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
}



/* NAVIGATION */
.logo {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://djonn.dk/logo.svg);
}

.inline {
    float: left;
}

.navwrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 128px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 995px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

nav a  {
    position: relative;
    top: 48px;
    display:block;
}
nav a div{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.25em;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

nav a:nth-of-type(1) div{
    border: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 760px) {
    .navwrap {
        width: 585px;
    }

    nav a div {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 761px) and (max-width: 995px) {
    .navwrap {
        width: 761px;
    }

    nav a div {
        font-size: 1.85em;
    }
}
```

For visual see: http://jsfiddle.net/djonn/DJG4L/

To clarify some of your comments:
- This is completely custom css, I'm using a css reset sheet.
- I wont use js instead of css, it would be instead of using the <a>-tag

Comment: can't you just use css to style this????

Comment: We need more data. Show us your **relevant** HTML and CSS. And please don't use JavaScript for something that CSS was made to do.

Comment: Have a feeling it'd be something simple like `a {font-size:12px;}` but without any code it's very hard to give an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like whatever you have in your CSS does not apply to the your links. You have to set your styles (a.hover a.active, etc.) Only having the H2 style does not give you the same result for H2 with a link (unless you have defined and applied a CSS class)

And please, follow the good advice thordarson gave -- do not use Javascript for something CSS was made to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your stylesheet looks something like this :

```
    html {
    font-size: SomeSize;
    etc.
    }
```

One thing I believe you can do is add this to your stylesheet :

```
    a:link, a:visited {
    font-size: TheSize;
    }
    a:hover {
    font-size: TheSize;
    }
```